# Excluding folder from PHPstorm indexing and error searching

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I am new to PHPstorm and running Laravel as my main framework.
In my vendors folder I have a Model, which I also have imported into my app/models folder, and now it's complaining about two models and functions which the same name, can I exclude the one folder in vendor/?

Comment: Have you tried to exclude it? If not then try and see what happens.

Comment: It will be generated again with every composer update.

Yeah excluded it, nothing changed, I think it's for git upload only...

Comment: Do a right click on the folder and select **Mark directory As** > **Excluded**

Comment: I have tried that, it does not work.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/e91e0514cefdf67c0f111872ff87aeed

There you can see that cmgmyr is excluded, and it is in that folder the secondary Message model is.

Comment: Can you try **File** > **Invalidate Caches / Restart** and then **Invalidate and Restart** and see if the problem remains

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Mark such duplicate folder as Excluded (either via right click menu in Project View panel.. or `Settings/Preferences | Directories`)
2. Make sure that such excluded folder is not listed under `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP --> Include paths`. If it does -- remove it from there as well.

Thing is: if `Add packages as libraries` option of Composer settings in PhpStorm was enabled then the package will be added as "external library" so it's not treated as an actual part of the project (does not participate in error checking/TODOs/usage referencing/refactoring operations etc) .. but it still included when resolving symbols (class names etc) even if it's marked as Excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Right click folder->Mark Directory As->Excluded.  This will prevent it from being indexed and included in project wide searches.  This is also handy if you are using a lot of packages and your Find in Project search results are junked up from a bunch of unrelated stuff from the Vendors or Cache folders